# How to create and rotate 3 Dimension object on z axis?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios6

I am new in OpenGL .I need to create model or image and rotation like https://www.foldable.me/foldables/new in this url .What should i use to work drawable model or image and how to work with this ...

Comment: This is, no offense, a fairly ambitious inquiry, and it's not at all clear what research you've done on the topic nor how deep your experience is in simpler animation on iOS. I'm not entirely sure if OpenGL is the best tool for you. It depends entirely upon (a) your level of expertise; and (b) what the app is going to do. But the Stack Overflow audience generally is not receptive to one or two line questions of "I want to do a really complicated task, show me how". You need to demonstrate that you've invested time and effort into the process.

Comment: If you haven't, I'd review the [Stack Overflow FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). This of this as a place to ask questions about "here's some of my existing code, but it's not working, how would you suggest I fix it" rather than something as open ended and broad as this question. 3D graphics is a non-trivial question, and you really need to demonstrate that you've done your homework. And I hope you take these comments in the spirit intended. I don't mean to be difficult. But we just can't help you unless you demonstrate a little more initiative.